# Модульное тестирование редиректов в asp.net mvc core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, тестирование

Проект asp.net core содержит простой контроллер для пары редиректов:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyCompany.ProjectName.WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class RedirectsController : Controller
    {
        [ActionName("z")]
        public IActionResult GroupBuyingForParticipants(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return this.RedirectToAction("OpenGroupBuyings", "GroupBuying", new { area = "Cabinet" });

            return this.RedirectToAction("Details", "Order", new { area = "Cabinet", groupBuyingId = id });
        }
    }
}
```

Сами редиректы должны работать так:

https://mysite.tld:8081/z/1 -> https://mysite.tld:8081/Cabinet/Order/Details?groupBuyingId=1
https://mysite.tld:8081/z -> https://mysite.tld:8081/Cabinet/GroupBuying/OpenGroupBuyings

И пару зелёных юнит-тестов:

```
using MyCompany.ProjectName.WebApp.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyCompany.ProjectName.WebAppUnitTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests for <see cref="RedirectsController"/>.
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixture]
    public class RedirectsControllerTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Z_WithId_RedirectToGroupBuying()
        {
            var controller = new RedirectsController();

            var result = controller.GroupBuyingForParticipants(123);

            Assert.IsInstanceOf<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
            var redirect = (RedirectToActionResult)result;
            Assert.AreEqual("Order", redirect.ControllerName);
            Assert.AreEqual("Details", redirect.ActionName);
            Assert.AreEqual("Cabinet", redirect.RouteValues["area"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(123, redirect.RouteValues["GroupBuyingId"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, redirect.RouteValues.Count);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Z_WhenEmpty_RedirectToOpenGroupBuyings()
        {
            var controller = new RedirectsController();

            var result = controller.GroupBuyingForParticipants(null);

            Assert.IsInstanceOf<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
            var redirect = (RedirectToActionResult)result;
            Assert.AreEqual("GroupBuying", redirect.ControllerName);
            Assert.AreEqual("OpenGroupBuyings", redirect.ActionName);
            Assert.AreEqual("Cabinet", redirect.RouteValues["area"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, redirect.RouteValues.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Сначала вообще был редирект только первый, потом добавился второй.

В чём проблема.

Было обнаружено при финальном смок-тестировании в браузере, что новый редирект не работает, хотя тесты как были зелёными, так и остались зелёными.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Виновник нашёлся быстро:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "short urls",
                template: "{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Redirects" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Забыл поставить `?` при рефакторинге, надо было добавляя к первому редиректу (с непустым id) второй редирект (с пустым id) поправить:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "short urls",
                template: "{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Redirects" }
            );
```

Как всё же грамотно поступить? Скажем, не использовать RedirectToAction, а что-то иное использовать, чтобы обойти мимо роутинга? Или тут только тесты на роутинг писать?

Comment: прям код ревью :) , а на выявленный баг написан тест?

Comment: я не спец конечно, но вроде контроллеры то тут не при чем, если у вас роутинг не сработал - то надо писать тест на маршруты